# Effects of joining the middle points of N parallel (2-battery serial sets)

Tags: batteries

Assume I need about 3V but large current:  First, I will need 2-battery serial set for the 3V.   Then, to meet large current need, I will need to parallel joint multiple those 2-battery serial sets.

What if I joint the middle points of all those 2-battery sets with wire?
Will it has some negative effects?

I asked this question because I have three "2-battery serial sockets" installed on a rotating plate.  If I joint the middle points, I can freely select to install 6 batteries or 4 batteries (the middle four, due to the need to balance the rotation).

See the pictures for detail.

[image: Normal Configuration]
[image: Mid Point Jointed Configuration]

In the normal configuration, installing 4 batteries in the center is not possible (have to install two on the side, which unbalances the rotation.

In the Mid-point jointed configuration, installing 4 batteries is possible.

But I am worried about other side effects...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftVyPC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The scheme risks the possibility of situation (c) which would not be OK.*

Leaving out the centre-tap connection makes it foolproof in that regard.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fx9Hjg.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. A better solution.*

How it works:

- Don't connect the centre holder mid-point.
- Cut the link in the outer holders and cross-connect them as shown so that the two outer cells are in series and the two inner cells are in series.
- Now the outer batteries only work if the correct pairs are inserted.
- Running with three or five batteries leaves the odd one out of circuit. Again this is safe.

[image]

*Figure 3. Wiring diagrm.*

Answer (score 1):

Joining the middle points has the same effect as the red wires below: -

[image]

So, if the batteries are capable of being paralleled, then it should be no problem but **do check** on the suitability of the batteries to be connected in parallel and read Bimpelrekkie's comment below this answer.

Comment: *but do check on the suitability of the batteries to be connected in parallel* That means: fresh (unused) batteries from the same package: OK mixing used, unused, non-identical, different brand batteries: **NOT OK** Rechargeble batteries: **NOT OK** (there can be **VERY LARGE** currents flowing when some are full, others less full, the currents will make the wires SMOKE. So: **NOT OK**.

Answer (score 1):

This arrangement is common with Li-ion cells, and will also work for most other battery chemistries, so long as you always ensure that all cells are at equal state of charge when you insert them into the parallel connection.  Otherwise, the weaker batteries will try to charge the stronger batteries, leading to wasted power and possibly fire.  If you go this route, a good rule of thumb would be to always replace all batteries at once with new ones, and never re-use old cells.  In particular, if you use it in the 4-cell configuration for some time, do NOT add two more without replacing the current four.

Note, however, that if you merely want to keep the weight distribution balanced with four batteries, you could simply omit the middle two and continue using the original circuit.

Comment: Good point.  Though my original idea for the central four is for less torque, more effective rotation performance.  But safety should be the number one.